# Updated my system, now VMWare can't update its kernel modules

Tags: 18.04, kernel, updates, vmware

After updating my system (with whatever was in the 18.04 repositories in recent weeks), VMWare can't update it's kernel modules. I hit Install on the VMWare Kernel Module Updater and it says it's trying to do "vmmon" and "vmnet". But it fails, saying "Unable to install all modules. See log /tmp/vmware-myhostname/vmware-1711.log for details. (Exit code 1)"

Here are the contents of this file: https://pastebin.com/hN6F6895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and installed the latest VMWare Player from VMWare and now everything works. I had been running 15.5.1, now I am on 15.5.6. You get a .bundle file - I just `chmod +x reallylongfilename` it and `sudo ./reallylongfilename` and Bob's your uncle.

If updating VMWare Player isn't an option, you might wish to look at this thread: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/623768

Somebody is running a repo that has patches needed to build host modules against recent kernels: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules (this is mentioned a few times in that thread).

But the simplest thing is just to go to the latest VMWare Player and see if that works - it did for me.